# Getting numeric precision in merge statement in Firebird

Tags: sql, merge, firebird, precision, numeric

I have latitude stored as numeric in a table (example 18.1659). I am using a merge statement to transfer that data into another table. All works except the data is entered into the new table as "18" only. Both fields are numeric which I thought was exact in Firebird. How can I get around this and enter the selected data exact into the new fields. Here is the sql I was using.

```
    merge into notary n
    using (select lat from Zip_codes where zipcode = n.zip) z
    on (n.zip = z.zipcode)
    when matched then update set lat = z.lat
```

I have tried using cast as double precision but that did not work either. If I understood why its happening I could probably figure out the solution but I'm not even sure why. Thanks

dialect 3
 TABLE: NOTARY
 FIELDS: LAT NUMERIC(18,0)
         LNG NUMERIC(18,0)

TABLE: ZIP_CODES
FIELDS: LAT NUMERIC(18,5)
        LNG NUMERIC(18,5)

Comment: please add to the topic the SQL dialect of your database and declarations (schemes) of both tables you use

Comment: personally i'd just store all the latitudes as Int64 after multiplying them by thousand :-)

Comment: also no point there in using derived tables, that misses the whole idea of MERGE command. http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=merge Just go with `merge into notary n using lat z on n.zip = z.zipcode ......`

Answer (score 2):

When I edited my question, I answered my own question. I didn't realize my numeric in Notary table were set to (18,0). Once I changed them to (18,5) all worked as it should.

Comment: still better de-wrap your MERGE command, no point to slow down server with many one-line requests instead of single one

Comment: Thanks, I only needed to use it one time to transfer some data on my local.

Comment: Actually what I ended up using was      'merge into notary n
  using zip_codes z
  on n.zip = z.zipcode 
  when matched then
    update set n.lat = z.lat'